# How To Approve An Edit To My Answer?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I have sufficient rep to be able to review and approve edits, but I don't know how to indicate approval.

One of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896069/not-sure-what-is-happening-in-my-while-loop/23896140#23896140) was edited today.  I particularly like the proposed modification, but for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to post it.

I've also seen edits that I would have liked to rollback but didn't know how.

Could someone tell me how to do both?  Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Your answer *hasn't* been edited.  And if there is a proposed edit, you didn't link to it, and there's no good way to see it given the answer.

Comment: There is no pending edit and there is no revision history so it has been rejected by others before you could get to it (assuming there was one in the first place). 

To rollback an edit you should go to the revision history of a post and click *rollback* at the appropriate revision.

Comment: This is the suggested edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4917440

Comment: Correct.  How could I log my approval of that edit.

Answer (score 3):

This is the proposed edit to your post:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4917440

It was rejected by 3 reviewers because edits are not supposed to edit an entirely new section of content, but rather for improving the presentation of existing content.

If the edit hadn't already been rejected, and was pending, you would see <kbd>approve</kbd> and <kbd>reject</kbd> buttons on that page.

You could roll back an improper edit by clicking "rollback" on the revision history.

Answer (score -2):

You are allowed to post a comment to your answer or add another answer.  If you like the content of the edit, you can certainly take that approach and mention the edit as your inspiration.

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the questions.  It doesn't tell him how to approve/reject a proposed edit to his answer, or how to roll back an edit to his answer he doesn't like.  He shouldn't be commenting on his own answer when that happens, nor should he be posting another answer.